# getting red alarm on dahdi show status command

Tags: centos-6, asterisk, configure

I am trying to configure dahdi on my centos system by following [this](http://striker24x7.blogspot.in/)
**my system.conf**

```
# Autogenerated by /usr/sbin/dahdi_genconf on Sun Sep 21 16:06:45 2014
# If you edit this file and execute /usr/sbin/dahdi_genconf again,
# your manual changes will be LOST.
# Dahdi Configuration File
#
# This file is parsed by the Dahdi Configurator, dahdi_cfg
#
# Span 1: TE2/0/1 "T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1" ESF/B8ZS RED 
span=1,1,0,esf,b8zs
# termtype: te
bchan=1-23
dchan=24
echocanceller=mg2,1-23

# Span 2: TE2/0/2 "T2XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2" (MASTER) ESF/B8ZS RED 
span=2,2,0,esf,b8zs
# termtype: te
bchan=25-47
dchan=48
echocanceller=mg2,25-47

# Global data

loadzone    = us
defaultzone = us
```

**my chan_dahdi.conf**

```
[trunkgroups]

[channels]
context=from-pstn-old
usecallerid=yes
callwaiting=yes
echocancel=yes
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
rxgain=0.0
txgain=0.0
pridialplan=unknown
switchtype=euroisdn
language = yes
relaxdtmf = yes
dtmfmode=auto
transfer=yes

;Span 1:
context=from-pstn
group=0
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1
echocancel=yes
signalling=pri_cpe
channel => 1-23,25-47
context=default
usecallerid=yes
callerid=asreceived
hanguponpolarityswitch=yes
answeronpolarityswitch=yes
cidstart=polarity_IN
cidsignalling=dtmf
hidecallerid=no
callwaiting=yes
usecallingpres=yes
callwaitingcallerid=yes
threewaycalling=yes
transfer=yes
canpark=yes
cancallforward=yes
callreturn=yes
echocancel=yes
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
relaxdtmf=yes
rxgain=0.0
txgain=0.0
group=1
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1
immediate=no
useincomingcalleridondahditransfer=yes
busydetect=yes
busycount=2
```

and on doing **module load chan_dahdi.so**

```
localhost*CLI> module load chan_dahdi.so
Loaded chan_dahdi.so
  == Registered application 'DAHDISendKeypadFacility'
  == Registered application 'DAHDISendCallreroutingFacility'
  == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf': Found
  == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf': Found
  == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/users.conf': Found
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 1: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 1, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 2: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 2, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 3: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 3, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 4: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 4, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 5: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 5, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 6: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 6, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 7: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 7, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 8: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 8, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 9: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 9, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 10: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 10, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 11: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 11, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 12: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 12, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 13: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 13, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 14: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 14, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 15: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 15, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 16: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 16, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 17: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 17, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 18: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 18, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 19: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 19, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 20: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 20, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 21: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 21, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 22: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 22, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 23: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 23, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 25: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 25, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 26: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 26, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 27: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 27, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 28: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 28, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 29: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 29, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 30: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 30, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 31: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 31, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 32: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 32, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 33: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 33, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 34: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 34, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 35: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 35, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 36: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 36, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 37: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 37, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 38: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 38, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 39: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 39, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 40: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 40, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 41: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 41, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 42: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 42, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 43: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 43, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 44: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 44, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 45: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 45, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 46: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 46, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 47: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 47, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 1 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 1: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 1, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 2 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 2: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 2, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 3 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 3: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 3, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 4 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 4: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 4, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 5 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 5: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 5, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 6 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 6: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 6, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 7 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 7: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 7, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 8 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 8: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 8, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 9 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 9: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 9, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 10 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 10: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 10, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 11 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 11: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 11, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 12 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 12: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 12, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 13 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 13: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 13, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 14 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 14: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 14, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 15 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 15: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 15, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 16 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 16: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 16, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 17 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 17: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 17, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 18 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 18: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 18, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 19 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 19: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 19, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 20 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 20: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 20, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 21 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 21: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 21, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 22 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 22: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 22, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 23 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 23: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 23, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 25 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 25: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 25, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 26 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 26: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 26, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 27 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 27: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 27, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 28 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 28: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 28, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 29 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 29: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 29, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 30 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 30: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 30, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 31 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 31: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 31, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 32 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 32: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 32, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 33 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 33: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 33, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 34 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 34: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 34, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 35 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 35: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 35, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 36 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 36: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 36, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 37 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 37: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 37, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 38 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 38: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 38, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 39 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 39: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 39, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 40 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 40: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 40, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 41 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 41: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 41, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 42 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 42: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 42, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 43 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 43: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 43, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 44 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 44: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 44, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 45 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 45: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 45, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 46 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 46: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 46, ISDN PRI signalling
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:13023 mkintf: Attempt to configure channel 47 with signaling ISDN PRI ignored because it is already configured to be ISDN PRI.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:8039 handle_alarms: Detected alarm on channel 47: Red Alarm
    -- Registered channel 47, ISDN PRI signalling
    -- Automatically generated pseudo channel
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:18700 process_dahdi: Ignoring any changes to 'userbase' (on reload) at line 23.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:18700 process_dahdi: Ignoring any changes to 'vmsecret' (on reload) at line 31.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:18700 process_dahdi: Ignoring any changes to 'hassip' (on reload) at line 35.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:18700 process_dahdi: Ignoring any changes to 'hasiax' (on reload) at line 39.
[Sep 21 17:03:33] WARNING[2877]: chan_dahdi.c:18700 process_dahdi: Ignoring any changes to 'hasmanager' (on reload) at line 47.
  == Starting D-Channel on span 1
  == Starting D-Channel on span 2
  == Registered channel type 'DAHDI' (DAHDI Telephony Driver w/PRI)
  == Manager registered action DAHDITransfer
  == Manager registered action DAHDIHangup
  == Manager registered action DAHDIDialOffhook
  == Manager registered action DAHDIDNDon
  == Manager registered action DAHDIDNDoff
  == Manager registered action DAHDIShowChannels
  == Manager registered action DAHDIRestart
  == Manager registered action PRIShowSpans
 Loaded chan_dahdi.so => (DAHDI Telephony Driver w/PRI)
```

My problem is that on doing dahdi show status in cli it shows red alarm.

Is there any more conifiguration i need?

Please help searching this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of the spans on your card depends primarily on what sort of lines your provider has given you so it is very hard for anyone to look at this configuration and know whether or not it is correct in your situation.

However, generally, the alarm state of the span (GREEN, RED, UNCONFIGURED, YELLOW) depends solely on the configuration in /etc/dahdi/system.conf and /etc/modprobe.d/dahdi.conf.

I can see your configuration is in a "standard" T1 PRI configuration. If you do not have a standard T1 PRI from your provider than you will need to check the documentation that came with your card to figure out how to change the configuration to match what what you get from your provider.

Answer (score 0):

Red alarm very likly mean you have no physical link. Or very bad configuration

Yellow alarm mean you have configuration error on logical level(like ecc or coding)

In your case very likly you need change this

```
esf,b8zs
```

to correct settings. For correct settings contact your provider. Also check wires.